# SlideToggle - reverse toggle and button hides

Tags: jquery, wordpress, button, reverse, slidetoggle

I have a problem with my jquery slideToggle.

Please visit http://en.fjordblink.webhipster.dk/foedekar/ and check out the button.

The following is my script i am using:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id="slidebottom" style="position: relative;">
<button>Button</button>
<div style="position: absolute;">Slide from top and down</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#slidebottom').on('click', clickButton);    
function clickButton()
{
  $(this).stop().slideToggle();
}
</script>
```

First of all, i want the text to be hidden, and first displayed when the button is presset. But they should still be able to hide the text again by pressing the button. So, i want the effect of slideToggle to be reversed.

Another problem is, that the button toggles as well. This should be visible all the time.
If i move the button outside the  then it will not toggle at all

All help appreciated! :)

Best Regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write button outside div like this and remove the position absolute otherwise you won't get the animation.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<div id="slidebottom" style="position: relative;">

    <div>
        Slide from top and down<br>
        Slide from top and down<br>
        Slide from top and down
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#slidebottom').stop().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS9Ds/) link is here

Comment: Thanks! 
Do you know if it is possible to map buttons like this? 
Please refer to http://uk.fjordblink.com/presentation/

It looks like the toggles here are mapped, or is this effect one in a different way?

If it is mapped, how is it possible to do this? I have a hard time mapping without make rect or cicles.

And one more thing: It still toggles from shown to hide. I want it to be hidden, and then shown when pressed. How is this done? Presiate the help :)

Comment: these are not image maps these are divs position absolute to the image where ever they are needed to be placed and you can call them just as normal toggle links/buttons, although image maps can also be written as toggles using jquery just change the selector to 'map#yourid'

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).find('div').stop().slideToggle();
```

instead of:

```
$(this).stop().slideToggle();
```

since you want to target the child div element.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2Qbu/)**